# Need to prove continuous periodic function of $\varphi (x) \equiv \psi(x)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions, continuity, periodic-functions

**Question**:

> Let two $\varphi(x) $ and $\psi(x)$  periodic and continous functions such that 
>   $$
> \lim_{ x\to\infty}(\varphi(x)-\psi(x))=0, \quad x\in \mathbb{R}.
> $$
>   Prove that
>   $$
> \varphi(x)\equiv \psi(x), \quad x\in \mathbb{R}.
> $$

It seems easy at first glance  to prove,however i have seen one a long  proof and didn't like it and i need to your help,who can prove it by short way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i suggest you read that long proof

Comment: Do you assume $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have the same period?

Comment: not same periodic

Comment: Is the $\equiv$ sign intentional or did you just mean $=$? If not please clarify.

Comment: This sign is also used for "identical equality" of functions; one writes f≡g for two functions f, g if we have f(x)=g(x) for all

Comment: Can you provide a reference or a link to the proof you have seen ? Why didn't you like it ?

Comment: i will try to write here that proof

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, continuity of only one of the two functions is sufficient. Suppose $\varphi$ is continuous.

Pick $x_0\in\Bbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$. Let $S$ and $T$ be the periods of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ respectively. Take $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(x_0)|<\epsilon/2$ and let $N\in\Bbb N$ be such that if $x>N$, then 
$$|\varphi(x)-\psi(x)|<\epsilon/2.$$
By [Dirichlet Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), there exists $n,k\in\Bbb N$ such that $|nS-kT|<\delta$. Moreover, by dividing $\delta$ by some constant depending on $x_0,N$ and $T$, we can make sure that $k$ is large enough so that $$x_0+kT>N.$$
Now, we have
$$|(x_0+nS)-(x_0+kT)|=|nS-kT|<\delta,$$
and hence
$$
\begin{align}
|\varphi(x_0)-\psi(x_0)| &= |\varphi(x_0+nS)-\psi(x_0+kT)| \\
&\leq|\varphi(x_0+nS)-\varphi(x_0+kT)|+|\varphi(x_0+kT)-\psi(x_0+kT)| \\
&<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
Since $x_0$ and $\epsilon>0$ are arbitrary, we conclude that $\varphi\equiv\psi$.

Comment: Spenser,did you use from continuity of functions or it doesn't nessasary?

Comment: thanks for help,but i think we should use from the continuity of functions in proof

Comment: @Nemo Continuity of one of the two function is necessary, I made a mistake earlier.

Comment: Nice proof! @Nemo: As a side note, the continuity assumption is not needed if the periods $S$ and $T$ are commensurable, that is, if there exists a rational number $n/k$ such that $nS=kT$.

Comment: Thanks,@Spenser,that was the proof i was looking for,thanks for help)